# Elevenlabs API unable to find ffmpeg on device (Python 3.11)

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, text-to-speech

When I'm trying to generate and play some speech using the elevenlabs API, the following text occurs at the very beginning of the program:
`Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work`
This is despite ffmpeg being installed correctly, and being recognized by Powershell. The relevent code is below.

```
import openai, requests, ffmpeg, pydub
from elevenlabs import *

set_api_key('i have my key here')
pydub.AudioSegment.converter = 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'

audio = generate(
  text=(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]),  #<--- This is correct, and grabs the text I need.
  voice="Charlie",
  model='eleven_multilingual_v1'
  )

play(audio)
```

I want it to simply play the audio generated through my default Windows playback device, but am instead met with the crash error upon playback; `ValueError: ffplay from ffmpeg not found, necessary to play audio.`

Comment: Post full stacktrace

Comment: Also check https://github.com/elevenlabs/elevenlabs-python/issues/56 https://github.com/elevenlabs/elevenlabs-python/issues/50 and https://github.com/elevenlabs/elevenlabs-python/issues/44

Comment: @Daviid

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ajkjd\OneDrive\Documents\Java\Python\AI\JPT\JPT_1_1_4.py", line 41, in <module>
    play(audio)
  File "C:\Users\ajkjd\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\elevenlabs\utils.py", line 25, in play
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: ffplay from ffmpeg not found, necessary to play audio. On mac you can install it with 'brew install ffmpeg'. On linux and windows you can install it from https://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Post that in the main question, you say ffmpeg.exe works in powershell, does ffplay.exe work too?

Comment: Never mind everything sorry! One of the links you had provided the solution. Thank you for your help (https://github.com/elevenlabs/elevenlabs-python/issues/56)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/elevenlabs/elevenlabs-python/issues/56

If you're using a virtual environment you might not have ffmpeg in the path, try adding:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + '/path/to/ffmpeg/bin/'
```